# String replace inside a for loop in bat script

Tags: batch-file, window

The replace is go well in this script. I am trying to make it dynamic.

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (C:\workspace\iwms_kw_patch_script\BuildPatchScript\140903111828_batch_file.txt) do (
    set lineString=%%a

    set str2=!lineString:C:\iwms_builder_working_directory\tmp\IWMS_KW_01_CBI_2014-003\=!
    echo !str2!

    echo IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 GOTO ERROR_HANDLER2 >> %output_file%
)
endlocal
```

And this one is not working..

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (C:\workspace\iwms_kw_patch_script\BuildPatchScript\140903111828_batch_file.txt) do (
    set to_replace=C:\iwms_builder_working_directory\tmp\IWMS_KW_01_CBI_2014-003\
    set lineString=%%a
    set str2=!lineString:%to_replace%=!
    echo !str2!

    echo IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 GOTO ERROR_HANDLER2 >> %output_file%
)
endlocal
```

Can I do a string replace with variable inside a for loop?
Thank :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the expansion of the variable. If the variable is modified inside the `for` block of code, to access its value inside the same block you need delayed expansion.

But you can not do something like `!lineString:!to_replace!=!` as the parser will interpret the opening `!` in `to_replace` as the termination og `lineString`.

So, you have two options.

The easiest one needs that value to be replaced to be known before the `for` command starts. Just define `to_replace` before the `for` command. When the parser reaches the `for` command the variable has the correct value and is properly expanded.

But if for any reason you have to define the value of the variable inside the `for` command, you will need to change your code as

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ( .... ) do (
    set "lineString=%%a"

    set "to_replace= .... "
    for %%b in ("!to_replace!") do set "str2=!lineString:%%~b=!"

    echo !str2!
)
```

This stores the value in the variable into a new `for` replaceable parameter that is used in the replace expression